# Jira in Python 2.7 maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, python-2.7, jira

I am using the JIRA library for python 2.7

The following line

```
jira_connection = JIRA(config['jira_address'], auth=(config['jira_username'], config['jira_password']))
```

gives the following error

> File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_27_64.pyx", line 1024, in
>   _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_27_64.ThreadTracer.**call** RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python
>   object

It worked fine for a while, then one day started giving this error. I don't really know what changed.

Would appreciate help or a workaround.

Comment: `It worked fine for a while, then one day started giving this error`  - did you update your software? Did you read the release notes? Software normally does not "stop working" under same conditions. Your question is unclear and does not provide means to replicate your problem - can you provide a [mcve] ? If not (what I think) it is very hard to help you out

Comment: @PatrickArtner I know it is hard. I just came to a new workplace, and this is the best information they have on this issue... I am assuming someone updated some dependency which affects this.

Comment: Same thing for me. No software updates - it just started to throw that recently

Comment: @SerafimSuhenky solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747461/jira-api-with-python-returns-error-401-on-valid-credentials

Comment: It happened the same to me, then I found that my auth tuple was (password, username) instead of (username, password)