# Jira API with python returns error 401 on valid credentials

Tags: python, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to use the Jira python library to do some quite basic things.
Even before doing anything, the constructor fails.

```
address = 'https://myaddress.atlassian.net'
options = {'server': address}
un = 'my@user.com'
#un = 'my' #also doesn't work
pw = 'the_pasSword!'
cookie = (un, pw)

j = JIRA(options, basic_auth=cookie)
```

This is ALL the code.

The last line fails with

> WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET
> https://myaddress.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [1/3]
> in 13.906688704524315s. Err: 401
>
> WARNING:root:Got recoverable error
> from GET https://myaddress.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will
> retry [2/3] in 4.071181495745648s. Err: 401
>
> WARNING:root:Got
> recoverable error from GET
> https://myaddress.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [3/3]
> in 6.266303262421157s. Err: 401

Trying the credentials manually on atlassian do work, and I am able to log in.

Any idea why this very straightforward attempt to connect wouldn't work?

Comment: Is this the library you're using? https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/

It looks like there are a few ways to authenticate to JIRA and it will depend on how your JIRA server is set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have been discussing deprecating passwords in basic auth. Try generating an API token and using that in replacement of your password.

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/

```
address = 'https://myaddress.atlassian.net'
options = {'server': address}
un = 'my@user.com'
#un = 'my' #also doesn't work
token = 'the_tokEn'
cookie = (un, token)

j = JIRA(options, basic_auth=cookie)
```

Comment: This worked! However... according to https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-user-privacy-api-migration-guide/ username usage will not be supported starting very soon. What more should I do?

Comment: Looks like you should just go ahead and test using the accountID as you linked to. Does it work when you use that?

Comment: The docs are extremely unclear on what gets deprecated. Contacted official support, and they said mail+token will continue working, so that's that, thanks!

Comment: From 2020-01-03 it does not work anymore with JIRA client ver 2.0.0, but still works with curl call: curl -v https://company.atlassian.net --user email:token

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
from jira.client import JIRA
import logging
import getpass
import datetime
import os

# Clearing the screen
os.system('cls||clear')
# Getting user authentication data
print 'Please enter your authentication data'
USER = raw_input('Username: ')
PASSWORD = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
print
JIRA_URL = "YOUR_JIRA_URL"
i = datetime.datetime.now()
TODAY = ("%s/%s/%s" % (i.day, i.month, i.year) )

def connect_jira(log, jira_server, jira_user, jira_password):
    '''
    Connects to JIRA

    Returns None on error
    '''
    try:
        log.info("Connecting to JIRA: %s" % jira_server)
        jira_options = {'server': jira_server}
        jira = JIRA(options=jira_options, basic_auth=(jira_user, jira_password))
                                        # ^--- Note the tuple
        return jira
    except Exception,e:
        log.error("Failed to connect to JIRA: %s" % e)
        return e

# Creating logger
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Creating a Jira connection object, jc
jc = connect_jira(log, JIRA_URL, USER, PASSWORD)
```

Comment: error 401. Why is this different?

The log outputs the html code for a page that says "error 401" more or less

Comment: @Gulzar
This works 100% on my install but, as you correctly found out in the other answer, in the new Jira version only tokens are accepted.